# Implementation of image parsing on an image tensor

Tags: python

I have an image tensor of size `[1,3,224,224]`. I want to apply the delta algorithm onto it (a type of parsing as such in NLP). I have referred to the paper to replicate the algorithm (Section5)  - https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.03479

The code I have used so far is as follows, but it uses too many iterations.

```
img=torch.squeeze(img)
i=0
j=1
d=torch.zeros(img.shape)
for i in range(img.shape[0]):
  d[i,0,:]=img[i,0,:]
  for j in range(img.shape[1]-1):
    d[i,j,:]=img[i,j,:]-img[i,j-1,:]
    for k in range(img.shape[2]-1):
      if (torch.abs(d[i,j,k])<torch.tensor(0.05)).any():
        d[i,j,k]=torch.tensor(0)
        img[i,j-1,:]=img[i,j-2,:]
      k=k+1
    img[i,j-1,:]=img[i,j,:]
    j=j+1
  i=i+1
```

This snippet reverts back the delta matrix onto my image reference matrix.

```
j=1
for j in range(img.shape[1]-1):
  img[:,j,:]=img[:,j-1,:]+d[:,j,:]
  j=j+1
```

I want to vectorize the code as much as possible however, could use some pointers on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
inputs=input.cuda()
        i=0
        j=1
        delta_inputs = torch.zeros(inputs.shape).cuda()
        d = torch.zeros(inputs.shape[0],inputs.shape[1],inputs.shape[2]).cuda()
        merge = torch.zeros(inputs.shape[0],inputs.shape[1],inputs.shape[2]).cuda()

        for i in range(inputs.shape[2]):  
          if(i == 0):
            d = inputs[:,:,i,:]
          else:
            d = inputs[:,:,i,:] - inputs[:,:,i-1,:]
            merge = d.abs()
            merge = torch.gt(merge, 0)
            d = d*merge.int()
    
  
          merge = d.bool()
          merge = merge.int()
   
          inputs[:,:,i,:] = inputs[:,:,i,:]*merge + inputs[:,:,i-1,:]*(torch.ones(inputs.shape[0],inputs.shape[1],inputs.shape[2]).cuda()-merge)
          delta_inputs[:,:,i,:] = d[:,:,:]        


        output = torch.zeros(delta_inputs.shape).cuda()

        for i in range(inputs.shape[2]):
            if(i == 0):
              output[:,:,i,:] = delta_inputs[:,:,i,:]
            else:
              output[:,:,i,:] = output[:,:,i-1,:] + delta_inputs[:,:,i,:]      
        
        input=output.cuda()
```